# Version field breaks orphanRemoval behavior on persistence layer

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, spring-data-jpa

I have entity `Event` with specified relation to another entity:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "event")
private Set<Reminder> reminders = new HashSet<>();
```

Everything worked fine (covered with tests, most important cases were checked) till I add version column into the `Event` entity.

```
@Column(name = "version_num")
@Version
private long version;
```

After adding `version` declared `orphanRemoval` is not working any more (tests shows it to me).

```
    saveDefaultEventAndCalendar();
    event.setReminders(Collections.emptySet());

    eventRepository.save(event);

    Event actualEvent = eventRepository.findOneByCalendarIdAndId(calendar.getId(), event.getId());
    assertThat(actualEvent, equalTo(event));
    assertThat(actualEvent.getReminders().size(), equalTo(0));

    List<Reminder> reminders = reminderRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(reminders.size(), equalTo(0));
```

and last line assertion is broken because of `reminders` are in db (`reminders` linked to the `actualEvent` but `actualEvent` does not have link any more).

I hope for explanation of this behavior of help with fix if it possible.

Comment: One more important thing. In debug mode it is passes time to time, behavior is not stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple answer:

```
entityManager.flush();
```

### Detailed answer:

The general idea of solution is to push cascade changes until transaction is not closed using newly injected `entityManager` (cascade changes hibernate use if special property annotation in relation).

```
...
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
...

@Test
public void save() {
    saveDefaultEventAndCalendarFullyInitialized();
    event1ForCalendar1.setReminders(Collections.emptySet());

    eventRepository.save(event1ForCalendar1);
    entityManager.flush();

    Event actualEvent = eventRepository.findOneByCalendarIdAndId(calendar1.getId(), event1ForCalendar1.getId());

    event1ForCalendar1.setVersion(event1ForCalendar1.getVersion() + 1);
    assertThat(actualEvent, equalTo(event1ForCalendar1));
    assertThat(actualEvent.getReminders().size(), equalTo(0));

    List<Reminder> reminders = reminderRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(reminders.size(), equalTo(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `reminder`'s life cycle to be dependent on `event` maybe consider using `@ElementCollection` instead of `@OneToMany`.

Comment: It is another approach that provides restricted relation tooling (and almost same for my case). I do not see reason why it should help in my case. Could you please add explanation for that please?